# nvd3, x-axis ticks are repeating for certain months

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

In nvd3 charts I could not able understand why there is repetition in the x-ticks for certain months. Is there any aproblem in my data or in my $scope.options1 settings ? In the attached image you can notice 09-13, 12-13, 03-14, 06-14 are repeating twice.
My data and options are as follows :

```
data = [{"values":[[1383264000000,1762],[1377990000000,1047.17],[1391212800000,1165.01],[1396306800000,3379.09],[1398898800000,2317.91],[1380582000000,1765.59],[1375311600000,650.2],[1388534400000,7008.33],[1393632000000,3121.12],[1385856000000,3518.7],[1404169200000,671.33],[1401577200000,1651.07]],"key":"GSR"}];



                    $scope.options1 = {
                        chart : {
                            type : 'lineChart',                             
                            height : 400,
                            text : 'Recovery ',
                            margin : {
                                "top" : 20,
                                "right" : 50,
                                "bottom" : 40,
                                "left" : 55
                            },
                            x : function(d) {
                                return d[0];
                            },
                            y : function(d) {
                                return d[1];
                            },
                            useVoronoi : false,
                            clipEdge : true,
                            transitionDuration : 1000,
                            useInteractiveGuideline : true,
                            xAxis : {
                                tickFormat : function(d) {                                  
                                    return d3.time.format('%m-%y')(
                                            new Date(d))
                                },
                                showMaxMin : false
                            },
                            yAxis : {
                                tickFormat : function(d) {
                                    return '$'
                                            + d3.format('.02f')(d / 1000)
                                            + 'K'
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that nvd3 creates a set number of ticks. The way around this is to modify the nvd3 framework a bit to allow you to use the standard d3 time intervals. See my answer to this question for details:

[With NVD3.js (nv.models.lineWithFocusChart), how do you set specific ticks on X-axis, when x values are dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446122/with-nvd3-js-nv-models-linewithfocuschart-how-do-you-set-specific-ticks-on-x/26492986#26492986)

After making the changes to the nvd3 framework, your code should look like this:

```
$scope.options = {
    chart : {
       ... 
        xScale : d3.time.scale(), // <-- explicitly set time scale
        xAxis : {
            ticks : d3.time.months, // <-- add formatter for the ticks
            tickFormat : function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%m-%y')(new Date(d))
            },
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I need some more time to accept the answer. I could not able to test your suggested fix in real time as our database is down.

Comment: Sorry Mike for the late, please see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2te6QVmErJpmUIBgYJEA?p=preview. The problem does not seem to be solved. I have taken latest nv.d3.js from https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/tree/master/lib and applied your solution at line 6870 in nv.d3.js but no success. Any suggestions to fix my plunker to avoid those repetitions?

Comment: Madasu: your nvd3 code change looked correct...but some of the code in your controller needed to be fixed. I updated link to add setting that was missing...also edited this answer to apply to your case specifically.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike it solved the problem and accepting the answer in both posts. I am facing some what similar problem while using nvd3 linewithfocuschart, please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251727/nvd3-chart-strange-behavior-with-date-range-slider?noredirect=1#comment41219879_26251727. Do you have any suggestion for me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done without having to modify to source of nvd3

e.g.

```
xAxis: {
  showMaxMin: true,
  ticks: d3.time.months,
  tickFormat: function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%B')(new Date(d));
  }
},
```