# nvd3 chart strange behavior with date range slider

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

While displaying nvd3 chart with Ajax requests, the charts are getting wired up. So I thought the problem is occurring due to asynchronous call delays (may be the chart is displaying before the full data is loaded, etc).  So I have used promises, but still I am getting the same problem. Please see the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/AcIpmki7GNvcoT6Z38Pm?p=preview.

If you change the date range slider, the main chart won't display properly. I am not sure where the problem is? After searching some of the posts in forum, I have come across some thing like gaps in the time series, is it due to that? If that is the case, how can I fix that time series gap issue? I searched nvd3 website, but I don't find any documentation regarding to fill up the gaps in time series data. Some of the forum posts suggests to use c3.js instead nvd3, but I don't  know is it really worth to shift to c3.js? Within my experience I feel nvd3 are the best and I don't feel like leaving nvd3.

If nvd3 website provides more samples with real time series data and documentation on some of the common issues like filling gaps in time series, sorting the data, etc it will be really helpful for the beginners.

As my project release dates are nearing, I am not sure what to do now ? Shifting to c3.js is the worst option for me. I have attached the error screen shot too from the same plunker.

I feel there is no problem with the sorting that I am doing with my json data:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(
                                        series, index) {
                                    series.values.sort(function(a, b) {
                                        return a.x - b.x;
                                    });
                                });
```

[image: Date Range Slider Mismatch]

Comment: Have a good look at your data. For category **MNK** on the `31/08/13` you have **5** data points with values `425.30, 2285.80, 3676.60, 23839.20, 31023.70, 38598` ?? Either you are using the wrong type of charts or you the data needs to be sorted out.

Comment: I agree with shabeer90, the data is funky. You have multiple values occurring at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues for you to look at:

1. I agree with shabeer90, the data is funky. You have multiple values occurring at the same time.
2. Your sort is correct, but where you have it in your code doesn't work...try adding it inside the response of the ajax call (right after setting $scope.data = data).
3. Also, you need to make the changes that I outlined in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446122/with-nvd3-js-nv-models-linewithfocuschart-how-do-you-set-specific-ticks-on-x/26492986#26492986) (to nvd3 in the lineWithFocusChart model).
4. Accessing the xScale is a little more tricky...on this chart you need to go through the lines:

> ```
> $scope.options = {
>     chart: {
>     type: 'lineWithFocusChart',
>     height: 450,
>     margin : {
>         top: 20,
>         right: 20,
>         bottom: 60,
>         left: 40
>     },
>     transitionDuration: 500,
>     lines : { // <-- add this
>         xScale : d3.time.scale()
>     },
>     lines2 : { // <-- add this too
>         xScale : d3.time.scale()
>     },
>     xAxis: {
>         ticks : d3.time.months, <-- add the time interval
>         axisLabel: 'X Axis',
>         tickFormat: function(d){
>             return  d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d))
>         }
>     },
>     x2Axis: {
>         tickFormat: function(d){
>             return  d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d))
>         }
>     },
>     yAxis: {
>         axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
>         tickFormat: function(d){
>             return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
>         },
>         rotateYLabel: false
>     },
>      y2Axis: {
>         tickFormat: function(d){
>             return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> };

Comment: Mike, Please see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2te6QVmErJpmUIBgYJEA?p=preview. The problem does not seem to be solved. I have edited my question with the error screen shot too.

Comment: Mike, No matter how many times I may attach the image it is not appearing. May be some issue with Stack Overflow website itself. But in any case in my above plunker, if you drag date range slider, you can notice the main chart ticks and graph lines does not appear properly. I have applied all the changes you have mentioned here. I have even used proper data here.

Comment: Madasu: in this plunker, you changed the equation in the sort, which causes the data to not be sorted correctly. I.e., You should be taking a.x - b.x, not a[0] - b[0]. Beyond that, I'm not sure. Working on this style chart today, so I'll let you know if I have any epiphanies...

Comment: Mike, not yet solved but I got some reference may be helpful for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/QiBdW7?p=preview. Please see the tick format calculations that were done there. May be in that line solves this problem too. If I succeed will update you. Thanks.  tickFormat: function(d) {    var dx = $scope.data[0].values[d].x;
                        var label = $scope.data[0].values[d].label;
                        return label ? label : d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx));
                    }