# nvd3, multibar with time series data, x-ticks are appearing separately for each check box item

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I am trying to use nvd3 for MultiBar chart with Time Series data. But in x-axis, the ticks are appearing separately for check box item. How can I fix this to make appear as normal multibar chart with dates on x-axis. Please find my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/GX5PH5xI2JZfylobO8M4?p=preview.

The following are my option settings:

```
  $scope.options = {
                chart : {
                            type : 'multiBarChart',
                            height : 400,
                            text : 'Credit Recovery',
                            x : function(d) {
                                return d[0];
                            },
                            y : function(d) {
                                return d[1];
                            },
                            useVoronoi : false,
                            clipEdge : true,
                            transitionDuration : 1000,
                            useInteractiveGuideline : true,
                          xScale : d3.time.scale(), // <-- explicitly set time scale
                            xAxis : {
                               ticks : d3.time.months, // <-- add formatter for the ticks
                                 tickFormat : function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%m-%y')(new Date(d))
        },
                                showMaxMin : false
                            },
                            yAxis : {
                                tickFormat : function(d) {
                                    return '$' + d3.format('.02f')(d )
                                }
                            }
                        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your data object is wrong, check his plunker i correct your data structure and the x,y attributes in the chart object. 
also the order function.

[plunker fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJV5pmPiFsKRg24SoeXu?p=preview)

```
$scope.data = [ {
          "values":[
            {x:1359072000000, y:10,label:'C1.1'},
            {x:1365116400000, y:30,label:'C1.2'},
            {x:1357516800000, y:40,label:'C1.3'},
            ],
        "bar":true,
        "key":"Carrier1"

        },
        {
          "values":[
            {x:1359072000000, y:30,label:'C2.1'},
            {x:1365116400000, y:10,label:'C2.2'},
            {x:1357516800000, y:79,label:'C2.3'},
            ],
          "bar":true,
          "key":"Carrier2"

        }
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks. It has solved the problem and I am accepting the answer. Do you have solution for a similar problem I had with line with focus chart? My post is at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251727/nvd3-chart-strange-behavior-with-date-range-slider/26638343?noredirect=1#comment41909680_26638343